# ld.exe: cannot find -lgtest only when using GNU make for windows

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gnu-make, googletest

I have been trying to compile a simple C++ program with the googletest libraries. I have gotten this to work using g++, however the project will soon become large and I want to be able to automate the compilation using make. I installed [GNU make for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) which I have tested on another program and **it works**. However when I try and use make to compile my googletest project I get the following error:

```
ld.exe: cannot find -lgtest
```

Here is the contents of my makefile:

```
all: test.exe
    test.exe: main.cpp
    g++ -o test.exe .\main.cpp .\sample1.h .\sample1.cc .\sample1_unittest.cc -ID:\...\gtest\include -LD:\D...\gtest\lib\ -lgtest_main -lgtest -Wall
clean:
    rm test.o test.exe
```

The weird thing is that if I run the same code from the command line, as follows, **it works** perfectly an I end up with my test.exe.

```
g++ -o test.exe .\main.cpp .\sample1.h .\sample1.cc .\sample1_unittest.cc -ID:\...\gtest\include -LD:\D...\gtest\lib\ -lgtest_main -lgtest -Wall
```

Does anyone know what this could be caused by and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find the problem! I'm still not sure why this is the case but apparently in make you have to specify paths like so:

```
-LD:\...\gtest\lib
```

And not like this (note the extra ):

```
-LD:\...\gtest\lib\
```

The error message makes sense since it must have been trying to search for the library in a path that looks something like this:

```
-LD:\...\gtest\lib\\
```

Which would obviously not work. I guess what threw me off was that the code worked when executed from the command line. It took me a while to see the inconstancy in my path specification and figure out that make doesn't want the extra '\'. Hopefully this will prevent someone else for wasting as much time as I did.